# AddIdentityServer() This call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, identityserver4, saml, saml-2.0

My project is working fine and building fine as well. However, when I add package **rsk.identityserver4.saml** it gives me error on this code.

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;

                // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
            })
```

and the error is

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentityServer(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<IdentityServer4.Configuration.IdentityServerOptions>)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServerServiceCollectionExtensions.AddIdentityServer(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action<Duende.IdentityServer.Configuration.IdentityServerOptions>)'    IdentityServer  D:\Office\GitHub\NLP\identityserver\IdentityServer\Startup.cs   58  Active
```

If I remove this package then it works fine again. How to overcome this issue ?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you have **IdentityServer4** and **Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer** installed.
You must delete one and bye error

Comment: Indeed. I think he installed both Duende an IdentityServer4